# /bin/sh: 0: command not found

Tags: php, shell

I have a following problem guys, my PHP script is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?PHP

 // Define the path to file
 $file = 'mydb.sql';

 if(!file)
  {
    // File doesn't exist, output error
    die('file not found');
  }
  else
  {
    // Set headers
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/x-sql ");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // Read the file from disk
    readfile($file);
   }
?>
```

Now I want to call my PHP script via crontab, and my cron command is:

```
0 0 * * * /web/conf/ -q /home/content/81/10928381/html/dumper/work/backup/pr_download.php
```

But why, every time i run my script, it's always sent me an error message : 
**/bin/sh: 0: command not found**

Can you help me guys?

Thanks

Comment: change `if(!file)` to `if(!$file)`

Answer (score 3):

what is `/web/conf/`? you are missing an executable command here... did you want `wget` ?

if you want to use your php executable instead, look where the executable is. eg `/usr/sbin/php`

then do

```
0 0 * * * /usr/sbin/php -f /home/content/81/10928381/html/dumper/work/backup/pr_download.php
```

Comment: I don't know the located of my PHP executable, does the location of PHP.ini is same with location of PHP executable?

Comment: @PruusianEkaP not necessarily. Its usually something like /usr/sbin/php , /bin/php , /usr/local/bin/php or something alike. Search for it. (Also try using `locate /php` to find it)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
php -f /home/content/81/10928381/html/dumper/work/backup/pr_download.php  >> /tmp/script_log.log
```

Comment: I have try your command, but it's dont give any effect to my script.

Comment: sorry, i was wrong when i wrote my first comment your script actually works. But, i don't check my /tmp folders. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same error when trying to execute a Windows file (DOS format) as a script.

Try this :

```
dos2unix pr_download.php
```

and then try running your script again.

Let me know if it works.